# List[i].Replace in for-loop won't return string

Tags: c#, string, list, replace

Trying to make hangman (i'm still a newbie) and the program chooses a random word out of a textfile ==> word turned into arrays. And i have to put it in a label while having the textlabel modified to what's in the `letterlist`. Thing is: it doesn't show **anything** in the label and i can't seem to figure out why.

So the for-loop is the modifier and when it has modified every string in the list it should return the word with the right letter or "_".

At first i tried is by doing: `letterlist[i] = Letter` or `letterlist[i] = "_"`, but would happen is if i typed in a right letter it would show only that letter.

For example: word = "pen". If i typed in "p", it resulted in "ppp".

```
letterlist = new List<string>();

char[] wordarray = woord.GetWordcharArray(); //word in charArrays
string newwordstring = new string(wordarray);

for (int i = 0; i < wordarray.Length; i++)
{
    letterlist.Add(" "); //adds empty strings in list with the length of the word 
}

/*
 * For-loop for every string in List to check and modify if it's correct or not 
 */
for (int i = 0; i < letterlist.Count; i++)
{
    if (letterlist[i].Contains(Letter) && newwordstring.Contains(Letter)) //right answer: letter[i] = Letter
    {
        letterlist[i].Replace(Letter, Letter);
    }
    else if (letterlist[i].Contains(" ") && newwordstring.Contains(Letter)) //right answer: letter[i] = "" 
    {
        letterlist[i].Replace(" ", Letter);
    }
    else if (letterlist[i].Contains("_") && newwordstring.Contains(Letter)) //right answer: letter[i] = "_"
    {
        letterlist[i].Replace("_", Letter);
    }
    else if (letterlist[i].Contains(" ") && !newwordstring.Contains(Letter)) //wrong answer: letter[i] = "" 
    {
        letterlist[i].Replace(" ", "_");
    }
    else if (letterlist[i].Contains("_") && !newwordstring.Contains(Letter)) //wrong answer: letter[i] = "_"
    {
        letterlist[i].Replace(" ", "_");
    }
}

/*
 * empty += every modified letterlist[i]-string
 */
string empty = "";
foreach (string letter in letterlist)
{
    empty += letter;
}
return empty;
```

New code but it only shows "___" ("_" as many times as the amount of letters as word has):

```
char[] wordarray = woord.GetWordcharArray(); //word in charArrays
string newwordstring = new string(wordarray); //actual word
string GuessedWord = new string('_', newwordstring.Length);//word that shows in form

bool GuessLetter(char letterguess)
{
   bool guessedright = false;

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(GuessedWord);

   for(int i = 0; i < GuessedWord.Length; i++)
   {
        if(char.ToLower(wordarray[i]) == Convert.ToChar(Letter))
        {
            builder[i] = wordarray[i];
            guessedright = true;
        }
    }

    GuessedWord = builder.ToString();
    return guessedright;
}

return GuessedWord;
```

Comment: C# strings are immutable, which means `letterlist[i].Replace(" ", "_")` doesn't do anything on its own. You need to reassign the result (`letterlist[i] = letterlist[i].Replace(" ", "_")`)

Comment: Also I don't see what is the goal behind `Replace(Letter, Letter)`

Comment: Last but not least, in your second `for` loop, every item in `letterlist` will be `" "` (because of previous `for` loop). Therefore most `if`s will never be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that C# string are immutable, which means `letterlist[i].Replace(" ", "_")` **does not** replace spaces with underscores. It **returns** a **new** string in which spaces have been replaced with underscores.
Therefore, you should reassign this result:

```
letterlist[i] = letterlist[i].Replace(" ", "_");
```

Second, `Replace(Letter, Letter)` won't do much.

Third, in your first `for` loop, you set every item in `letterlist` to `" "`.
I don't understand then why you expect (in your second `for` loop) `letterlist[i].Contains("_")` to **ever** be `true`.

Finally, I'll leave here something you might find interesting (especially the use of `StringBuilder`):

```
class Hangman
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Hangman item = new Hangman();
        item.Init();

        Console.WriteLine(item.Guessed); // ____

        item.GuessLetter('t'); // true
        Console.WriteLine(item.Guessed); // T__t

        item.GuessLetter('a'); // false
        Console.WriteLine(item.Guessed); // T__t

        item.GuessLetter('e'); // true
        Console.WriteLine(item.Guessed); // Te_t
    }

    string Word {get;set;}
    string Guessed {get;set;}

    void Init()
    {
        Word = "Test";
        Guessed = new string('_',Word.Length);
    }

    bool GuessLetter(char letter)
    {
        bool guessed = false;

        // use a stringbuilder so you can change any character
        var sb = new StringBuilder(Guessed);

        // for each character of Word, we check if it is the one we claimed
        for(int i=0; i<Word.Length; i++)
        {
            // Let's put both characters to lower case so we can compare them right
            if(Char.ToLower(Word[i]) == Char.ToLower(letter)) // have we found it?
            {
                // Yeah! So we put it in the stringbuilder at the same place
                sb[i] = Word[i];
                guessed = true;
            }
        }

        // reassign the stringbuilder's representation to Guessed
        Guessed = sb.ToString();

        // tell if you guessed right
        return guessed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that for-loop with the StringBuilder, but i have to turn `Word` into arrays to make it work right? And you wouldn't be able to use `ToLower` for the arrays would you? (p.s. i had to look up what a stringbuilder was xd)

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai no, you do not need to turn `Word` into an array. The code I gave here runs as is without having to change anything. I "lowered" the `Word` so that `t` matches both first and last `T`s in `"Test"`. Stringbuilder is a cool magical thing that allows you to change anything you want in a string: you create it, you play with it, and once you're done, just reassign its string representation to your actual string. Et voilà!

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai I added some comments to my code. Just tell me if you need more clarifications

Comment: `return GuessedWord;` at the end of your code makes me think that you placed my code *inside a function*. Am I right? My `Hangman` is a *class*, which means you have to create an object (`Hangman myHangman = new Hangman();`) then initialize it (`myHangman.Init();`) then just call `myHangman.GuessLetter(Letter);` whenever the user inputs a letter, and you get your guessed word by reading `myHangman.Guessed`. The reason why you always get `____` is that you never call `GuessLetter`

Comment: I don't have InIt(), but i did call the method though. I have 3 classes: _word_, _hangman_ and _form1_ that connects with the "UI". And in the class _form1_ i call the method `lblAnswer.Text = game.ApplyLetterToForm();` and in `game.ApplyLetterToForm()` is the new code. Is that wrong, because i do return the `Guessed`, right? (object in form1: `Hangman game = new Hangman(lblAnswer.Text, lblWrongLetters.Text);`)

Comment: In your form, you should have a field `Hangman game;` and initialize it `game = new Hangman(wordToGuess);` for example. Then whenever the user enters a letter, you should call `game.GuessLetter(letter)`. Right after that, you can read `game.Guessed` which is your masked word. I fail to see what's causing you trouble, and not being able to read your full code doesn't help with this :/

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much! :D I tried to implement `InIt()` in my code and it still didn't work until i realized i did something newby: `private char[] wordarray { get; set; }` and i tried to get set it with `char[] wordarray = woord.GetWordcharArray();` xD